# Navigation graph won't use default arguments in deeplink

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

I have a fragment in a navigation graph with two parameters (`ids: List<Int>?` and `name: String?`) - these both have default values set (both set to `@null`).

I have created a deeplink to this fragment from the pattern `mysite.com/{name}` but after upgrading to navigation version 2.4.0-alpha08 I get this error when running my app:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Deep link mysite.com/{name} can't be used to open destination Destination(com.mysite:id/myFragment) class=com.mysite.MyFragment.
    Following required arguments are missing: [ids]
```

As the exception is thrown when inflating my MainActivity.xml, it seems like the default value for `ids` is being ignored when validating the deeplink.

This didn't happen in version 2.4.0-alpha06.

Is this a bug in this version of the navigation component (I'll raise a bug if so), or is this just better validation in that component revealing a bug in my code - if so, what's the fix?

Answer (score 3):

Horribly, here's the hack I'm using.

URL parameters are optional if their value has a default set, so my deeplinks in the navigation graph now look like this:

`mysite.com/{name}?this_wont_ever_really_happen={ids}`

which matches the url `mysite.com/{name}` because `ids` has a default value (of `@null`)

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack Navigation [version 2.5.0-alpha04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3J10.png) release note mentions a fix to solve this kind of problem:

[image]